# Programatically access Windows Password Policy settings

Tags: c#, wmi, wmi-query

I am developing a .NET website that is using Windows Authentication.

I have a requirement to make website password policy exactly same as the Windows password policy which is under: (*gpedit.msc*)
**Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Account Policies\Password Policy**

How can I programmatically access these Windows password policy settings in C#?

PS I had a look at Windows Management Instrumentation but couldn't find the correct path which points to Windows password policy.

```
using System.Management;
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(new ManagementPath("some_path"))
```

PS2 Please don't tell me to modify *web.config* file and changing   tags. I know it's the easiest solution, however, I need the website to automatically match the default password policy of Windows host PC... sounds weird but that's the requirement.

Comment: " that is using Windows Authentication." - if you're using Windows Authentication then Windows will enforce the password policy by itself, you don't need to do anything other than call Win32's accounts/password functions yourself rather than reimplement a password-policy engine yourself.

Comment: @Dai Why not post this as an answer?

Comment: @Dai answer is correct, however, I'm still looking for a way to access these settings. I need it to for the UX, to list all password requirements on the website. I tried things like System.Web.Security.Membership.MinRequiredPasswordLength and it's returning 0 which is wrong.